# Matplotlib streamplot with streamlines that don't break or end

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to make a streamplot with lines that don't stop when they get too close together. I'd rather each streamline be calculated in both directions until it hits the edge of the window. The result is there'd be some areas where they'd all jumble up. But that's what I want.

I there anyway to do this in matplotlib? If not, is there another tool I can use for this that could interface with python/numpy?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Y,X = np.mgrid[-10:10:.01, -10:10:.01]
U, V = Y**2, X**2
plt.streamplot(X,Y, U,V, density=1)
plt.show(False)
```

[image: Stream plot example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Matplotlib version 3.6.0, an optional parameter `broken_streamlines` [has been added](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#streamplot-can-disable-streamline-breaks) for disabling streamline breaks.

Adding it to your snippet produces the following result:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Y,X = np.mgrid[-10:10:.01, -10:10:.01]
U, V = Y**2, X**2
plt.streamplot(X,Y, U,V, density=1, broken_streamlines=False)
plt.show(False)
```

[image: a stream plot with continuous streamlines]

### Note

This parameter just extends the streamlines which were originally drawn (as in the question). This means that the streamlines in the modified plot above are much more uneven than the result obtained in the other answer, with custom `start_points`. The density of streamlines on any stream plot does not represent the magnitude of `U` or `V` at that point, only their direction. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html) for the `density` parameter of `matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot` for more details on how streamline start points are chosen by default, when they aren't specified by the optional `start_points` parameter.

For accurate streamline density, consider using [matplotlib.pyplot.contour](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html), but be aware that `contour` does not show arrows.

### Choosing start points automatically

It may not always be easy to choose a set of good starting points automatically. However, if you know the streamfunction corresponding to the flow you wish to plot you can use [matplotlib.pyplot.contour](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) to produce a contour plot (which can be hidden from the output), and then extract a suitable starting point from each of the plotted contours.

In the following example, `psi_expression` is the streamfunction corresponding to the flow. When modifying this example for your own needs, make sure to update both the line defining `psi_expression`, as well as the one defining `U` and `V`. Ensure these both correspond to the same flow.

The density of the streamlines can be altered by changing `contour_levels`. Here, the contours are uniformly distributed.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sy

x, y = sy.symbols("x y")
psi_expression = x**3 - y**3
psi_function = sy.lambdify((x, y), psi_expression)

Y, X = np.mgrid[-10:10:0.01, -10:10:0.01]
psi_evaluated = psi_function(X, Y)
U, V = Y**2, X**2
contour_levels = np.linspace(np.amin(psi_evaluated), np.amax(psi_evaluated), 30)

# Draw a temporary contour plot.
temp_figure = plt.figure()
contour_plot = plt.contour(X, Y, psi_evaluated, contour_levels)
plt.close(temp_figure)

points_list = []

# Iterate over each contour.
for collection in contour_plot.collections:
    # Iterate over each segment in this contour.
    for path in collection.get_paths():
        middle_point = path.vertices[len(path.vertices) // 2]
        points_list.append(middle_point)
# Reshape python list into numpy array of coords.
stream_points = np.reshape(np.array(points_list), (-1, 2))

plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=1, start_points=stream_points, broken_streamlines=False)
plt.show(False)
```

[image: a stream plot with continuous streamlines, where the start point have been chosen automatically by computing a contour plot first]

Comment: I'm glad they added this. It's usually not as easy to manually pick a good set of starting points as it was in my example. I wonder if `contour` could be used together with `streamplot` somehow - maybe if the contours can be extracted so you can pick one point in each contour as a starting point or something.

Comment: @argentum2f yes, this is very possible! I have updated my answer with an example snippet

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I've figured out I can get mostly what I want by turning up the `density` a lot and using custom start points. I'm still interested if there is a better or alternate way to do this.

Here's my solution. Doesn't it look so much better?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Y,X = np.mgrid[-10:10:.01, -10:10:.01]
y,x = Y[:,0], X[0,:]
U, V = Y**2, X**2
stream_points = np.array(zip(np.arange(-9,9,.5), -np.arange(-9,9,.5)))
plt.streamplot(x,y, U,V, start_points=stream_points, density=35)
plt.show(False)
```

[image: Streamplot example]

**Edit:** By the way, there seems to be some bug in `streamplot` such that `start_points` keyword only works if you use 1d arrays for the grid data. See [Python Matplotlib Streamplot providing start points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928767/python-matplotlib-streamplot-providing-start-points)